# How to fix warning Missing class: org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier when build Android

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Got warning
Missing class: org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier when build Android

I wonder how to fix this

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6299